# How to authenticate users from multiple client apps using Identity server at different user stores?

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, identity

Can anyone please recommend a best pattern to solve the below use case with identity? I will try to explain what we are up to now and what we are thinking to do.

Technology Stack: Identity server 4, ASP.net core APIS (10), Angular SPA, Java web site and MVC website.

We started using Identity server 4 from last 2 years and I have fair understanding of how it works, extension points, asp.net identity etc.. First we started this for machine to machine communication which is pretty simple using client credentials.
Later we wanted to integrate Identity server for Angular SPA client which has users stored in Active directory and they don’t want users to be created in Identity server database. So I created some handler in identity server when the request is redirected to login page and based on the client I have checked against AD and added roles to the token. This worked fairly OK for that single SPA client.

Now we are thinking to integrate another SPA client, one Java website and another website with Identity server and the challenge is all those applications have users in their own database so I am not sure what is best strategy to go for to make it work for all these applications.

Based on my research and extensive reading on identity server and from stack overflow discussions I came up with these options. Please let me know what’s your thoughts are to implement SSO across these applications.

Option 1 : Keep users and passwords at multiple places( application specific databases which is current scenario) and write handlers in Identity server to check the users against these data stores and returns cookie/token. This one sorts of works but has draw backs of exposing/integrating identity server to all these external applications to validate user and exposing application specific logic to Identity server. If we go with this, where does the user resets password as the user does not exists in identity server database? and also what the unique userid we will set to sub claim as the user does not exists in identity server?

Option 2 : Migrate identity information(user name,password,email etc..) from different stores and keep authorization/permissions info in the application database. This one makes sense but kind of duplicating users in identity and other places and how to sync the user at two places when a user is created in identity. and also how to correlate the sub (userid) returned from identity to the userid in the local database to get permissions.

Option 3 : If we implement Option 1 without having users exists in identity server database by writing custom logic, what are the issues we are going to face to achieve SSO across applications? what is the unique userid we will set to sub claim as the user does not exists in identity server?

Thanks in advance.